# Querying two array fields and getting positional result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I've been trying to do important update operations using *two-phase commit* method. Unfortunately, the field that will be updated in an array. But the same document have to has a pendingTransactions field to store the current transactions. And according to [this documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitation), MongoDB doesn't support positional update
if two array fields are in the query document.

*Is there any chance to solve this situation?*

***Other Additional informations and 'Correct Results' using Two Array Fields In The Query***

Actually I used a second array in query document without knowing the problem. It works stable. When testing, I encountered with the problem at another update operation. So, the first query response correctly at every time.

the stable part is like the below. With `$ne` operator it works correct;
`invoices` and `pendingTransactions` are Array fields

```
var query = { 
    _id: customer_id, 
    invoices: { $elemMatch: { 'year': 2015, 'month': 8 } },
    pendingTransactions: { $ne: transaction_id }        
}

Customers.findOne(filter, { 'invoices.$' }, function(err, customer){
    /* Positional operator $ works correct */
}
```

the unstable part is like the below;

```
var query = { 
    _id: customer_id, 
    invoices: { $elemMatch: { 'year': 2015, 'month': 8 } },
    pendingTransactions: transaction_id
}   

Customers.findOne(filter, { 'invoices.$' }, function(err, customer){
    /* Positional operator $ doesn't work correct */
}
```